# How can I resolve composer installation problems?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

This is the error message I'm getting when I try a composer update.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for ****/silex-php 1.1 -> satisfiable by ****/silex-php[v1.1].
    - ****/silex-php v1.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.3.x-dev, 2.4.x-dev, 2.5.x-dev, 2.6.x-dev, 2.7.x-dev, 2.8.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I want any symfony/framework-bundle that is a) stable and b) greater than 2.3.

Comment: What does your composer.json look like?

Answer (score 0):

This error went away by itself.

Sometimes it help to remove the whole vendor folder and try again instead of trying to debug this very specific dependency problems.